# Javascript - How to return the time where I live?

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone

So I'm doing codecademy and the current section I'm on wants you to return the current time and display different messages depending on the current time.

You could pass with any time but I'd rather configure it to be my timezone and even extra if anyone knows, the time zone that the person accessing the web page is in.

Currently I have this.

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);
```

This prints GMT time.

What I'd like is GMT +10.

I knows there's a function that returns your timezone

```
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

But I'm not too sure as to how I get this to interact with the Date function so that it prints the time in this timezone.

Thanks!

Regards,

Matt

**SOLVED:** Was a bug in codecademy.

Comment: `var d = new Date();
console.log(d);` - for me returns the date in my exact timezone: `Tue May 29 2012 14:02:01 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)`

Comment: as far as I know, `Date()` returns the date in your PC's timezone, you use `getTimezoneOffset()` if you need to, for instance, calculate the time in different `GMT`

Comment: If you tell your OS that you live in Greenwich, it won't try to correct you :)

Comment: @zerkms That is the time it is returning for me, unfortunately this is 2 hours ahead of my time zone.

Comment: @Matt: what browser do you use? Are you sure your OS timezone is specified correctly?

Comment: @zerkms Currently using google chrome, my OS time is set to UTC+10

Comment: @zerkms You made me think that perhaps this was just a bug on codecademy, upon further testing I do get my timezone returned when using other javascript testers but codecademy only returns GMT time.

Solved I guess, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Date methods.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

For example, `d.getDate()` will return the local date, whereas `d.getUTCDate()` will return the GMT-based date.